# Using nested list comprehensions to create an accelerated increase

Tags: python

I want a list made out of numbers increasing with a multiplier which increases in every step. The basic nested `for` loop is easy.

```
numbers = []
i = 1
for x in range(50):
    numbers.append(x*i)
    i += 1
```

But when I try to do it with list comprehension, it doesn't work like I want it to be.

```
numbers = [x * i for x in range(50) for i in range(50)]
```

I know I did something wrong with the list comprehension but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: "It doesn't work like I want it to be" is not very descriptive.

Comment: range starts with `0` use `range(1, 51)`, like `[x * i for x,i in zip(range(50), range(1, 51))]` use `zip` to combine them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should behave the same way your for loop does.

```
numbers = [x * (i+1) for x, i in zip(range(50), range(50))]
```

or

```
numbers = [x * i for x, i in zip(range(50), range(1, 51))]
```

or even without i

```
numbers = [x * (x+1) for x in range(50)]
```

Comment: A logical and beautiful answer.